# Slurm oversubscribe GPUs

Tags: gpu, slurm

Is there a way to oversubscribe GPUs on Slurm, i.e. run multiple jobs/job steps that share one GPU? We've only found ways to oversubscribe CPUs and memory, but not GPUs.

We want to run multiple job steps on the same GPU in parallel and optionally specify the GPU memory used for each step.

Comment: Check the answer given in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200926/how-to-access-to-gpus-on-different-nodes-in-a-cluster-with-slurm

Comment: @BubEspinja That answer seems to be the opposite direction of what we're aiming for. We don't want to use the GPUs from several nodes for a single job but a single GPU for multiple jobs.

Or are you referring to the GPU virtualization mentioned in the cited paper and saying that that might be the only real solution?

Comment: As far as I know, in Slurm you cannot share a GPU among several different jobs. For this reason, GPU virtualization is presented as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way of doing that is to have the GPU defined as a `feature` rather than as a `gres` so Slurm will not manage the GPUs, just make sure that job that need one land on nodes that offer one.

Comment: How would we manage the available GPUs and make sure that the usage is evenly distributed then? Especially since some jobs do need the whole GPU. Can Slurm directly manage the GPU memory?

Comment: You could defined a custom `gres` with the memory of the GPU.

Comment: We've experimented with using GPU memory as a gres. However, there were two issues: 1. We couldn't tell Slurm that a node had 4 GPUs with 12GB memory each. 2. Jobs were assigned correctly, however there was nothing that limited the job to its assigned memory. I.e. a job could be assigned to 4GB but then in fact use 12GB.